# Copy and paste dynamic range - paste under row where there is value

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range

I am trying to copy e3:u3, and paste underneath the row that has the last value. So for the latest entry, it would be e25 onwards. Next month would be e26, etc.

[image]

So far, I could only make it work manually where the destination has to be updated every entry.

Can this be done? I'd really appreciate some help - thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Get the last row in column E using this code

Dim LastRow as integer
LastRow  = Activesheet.Range("E" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

after copy paste with below code
Activesheet.Range("E" & LastRow + 1 & ":U" & LastRow + 1).paste

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to define a target range, and set that range to the first row below the last entry. The source range will of course remain constant.

The crucial statement is this:

```
Set rngTarget = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

That statement says

- Start in column E in the bottom row in the worksheet (`.Rows.Count`)
- Go up to the last entry in column E  (`.End(xlUp)`)
- Move one row below that (`.Offset(1, 0)`)

```
Sub CopyToNewRow()
    Dim rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rngSource = .Range("e3:u3")
        Set rngTarget = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        
        rngSource.Copy rngTarget
    End With
End Sub
```